# How to save model data using realm?

Tags: java, model, realm

I am developing a chat app and successfully saved User model class to the realm but now I want to save messages to the realm so that when user start app able to see previous chat history and messages.

> below my SavedMessages model class

```
@RealmClass
```

public class SaveMessage extends RealmObject {

```
private int mId;
private String mUsername;
private String mContent;
private Date mCreatedAt;
private boolean mRightMessage;
private String mPictureString;
private String mType;

public SaveMessage(int id, String username, String content, Date createdAt, boolean isRightMessage) {
    mId = id;
    mUsername = username;
    mContent = content;
    mCreatedAt = createdAt;
    mRightMessage = isRightMessage;
}

public SaveMessage() {

}

public int getId() {
    return mId;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return mUsername;
}

public String getContent() {
    return mContent;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return mCreatedAt;
}

public void setDate(Date createdAt) {
    mCreatedAt = createdAt;
}


public boolean ismRightMessage() {
    return mRightMessage;
}

public int getmId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setmId(int mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}

public String getmUsername() {
    return mUsername;
}

public void setmUsername(String mUsername) {
    this.mUsername = mUsername;
}

public String getmContent() {
    return mContent;
}

public void setmContent(String mContent) {
    this.mContent = mContent;
}


public boolean ismRightMessage(String isRightMessage) {
    return mRightMessage;
}

public void setmRightMessage(boolean mRightMessage) {
    this.mRightMessage = mRightMessage;
}

public String getPictureString() {
    return mPictureString;
}

public void setPictureString(String pictureString) {
    mPictureString = pictureString;
}

public String getType() {
    return mType;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    mType = type;
}
```

}

below User.java

```
@RealmClass
public class User extends RealmObject implements IChatUser {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    @Ignore
    Bitmap icon;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(int id, String name, Bitmap icon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }


    @Override
    public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

> below Realm implementation where I have implemented realm database

```
        Realm.init(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();

        User userModel =  realm.createObject(User.class);


        Integer userId = Integer.valueOf("0");
        String userName = "Michael";

        userModel.setId(userId);
        userModel.setName(userName);
        //userModel.setIcon("icon");
        Integer userId1 = Integer.valueOf("1");
        String userName1 = "Lily";



        userModel.setId(userId1);
        userModel.setName(userName1);


        realm.commitTransaction();


        RealmResults<User> userModels = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
        for (User user : userModels) {
            Integer getId = Integer.valueOf(user.getId());
            String getName = user.getName();

        }
 SaveMessage saveModel = realm.createObject(SaveMessage.class);

    saveModel.setmId(Integer.parseInt("id"));
    saveModel.setmUsername("userName");
    saveModel.setmContent("content");
    saveModel.ismRightMessage("isRightMessage");

    RealmResults<SaveMessage> savesModels = realm.where(SaveMessage.class).findAll();
    for (SaveMessage saveMessage : savesModels) {
        Integer getId = saveMessage.getId();
        String getName = saveMessage.getUsername();
        String getContent = saveMessage.getContent();
        String rightMessage = String.valueOf(saveMessage.ismRightMessage());

        realm.commitTransaction();

    }

        //Load saved messages
        loadMessages(realm);
```

Comment: You've not asked a question there. What problem are you trying to fix? Hint: you are not creating two users in your code - you are creating one user (Michael, 0), and then overwriting the data with (Michael, 1). Only the second remains. Also, why not `int userId = 0;`?

Comment: @Chris Shaw I want to ask how can I convert Date to string in model class becuase it is giving an error

Comment: @Chris Shaw please check updated code

Comment: Which line is the error on? What is the error? If I was you I'd find a decent tutorial for what you're trying to do, because your code is way off - too much to correct here.

Comment: @Chris ShawI want to save chat history and messages to the realm so that when a user launches the app they can see message history and messages. I read the tutorial done step by step.