# How to convert Date to string in realm

Tags: java, date, realm, data-conversion

I am developing app now I want to convert Date to String in realm but I have tried but I can't achieve what I want

below SaveMessage model class

```
@RealmClass
public class SaveMessage extends RealmObject {


    private int mId;
    private String mUsername;
    private String mContent;
    private Date mCreatedAt;
    private boolean mRightMessage;
    private String mPictureString;
    private String mType;

    public SaveMessage(int id, String username, String content, Date createdAt, boolean isRightMessage) {
        mId = id;
        mUsername = username;
        mContent = content;
        mCreatedAt = createdAt;
        mRightMessage = isRightMessage;
    }

    public SaveMessage() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mUsername;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return mContent;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return mCreatedAt;
    }

    public void setDate(Date createdAt) {


        mCreatedAt = createdAt;
    }
```

below my Date conversion

> SimpleDateFormat input = new
>   SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"); SimpleDateFormat
>   output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

```
Date d = new Date();
try {
    d = input.parse(output);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public boolean ismRightMessage() {
    return mRightMessage;
}

public int getmId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setmId(int mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}

public String getmUsername() {
    return mUsername;
}

public void setmUsername(String mUsername) {
    this.mUsername = mUsername;
}

public String getmContent() {
    return mContent;
}

public void setmContent(String mContent) {
    this.mContent = mContent;
}


public boolean ismRightMessage(String isRightMessage) {
    return mRightMessage;
}

public void setmRightMessage(boolean mRightMessage) {
    this.mRightMessage = mRightMessage;
}

public String getPictureString() {
    return mPictureString;
}

public void setPictureString(String pictureString) {
    mPictureString = pictureString;
}

public String getType() {
    return mType;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    mType = type;
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you want a string? Why have you asked a new question, when you already have [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55995015/how-to-save-model-data-using-realm).

Comment: becuase I have to fix this one first I already fixed that

Comment: Don’t use the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. Instead use `Instant`, `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter`and possibly more classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Please, “can't achieve what I want” is vague. Please specify precisely what you want and precisely how what you get differs. If you get any error message, please quote verbatim in the question (paste into the question). Then we can probably faster spot what’s wrong (apart from using the old and troublesome classes) and help you better.